# Angled brackets being escaped from url in PHP

Tags: php, url, curl

I am trying to call the USPS API that takes in the zip code and returns XML containing the City Name of the given zip code.

Here is the URL they require:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup 
&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="xxxxxxx"><ZipCode ID= "0"> 
<Zip5>90210</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>
```

In my PHP file, when I echo out the above URL, this is what I get:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=90007
```

All the XML part of the URL is missing. I need to get curl data from the URL.

Anyone know what I could be missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used XML in a url before, so i am not sure what I should be doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone know what I could be missing?

Probably. Maybe, yes. What you describe in your posting sounds like an encoding problem. So you are missing the right encoding.

As you are talking about an URL that is likely URL encoding. Some characters - like space - have a special meaning inside an URL so you can not just use any character as you like, but you need to encode all characters properly.

The exact description how you need to formulate an URL incl. the exact description how URL encoding works is outlined in [*2. Characters* in the internet standard RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2).

PHP functions related to URL encoding are *`urlencode()`* and *`rawurlencode`* and more likely useful in your case [*`http_build_query()`*](http://php.net/http_build_query).

Comment: can you be more elaborate? I've never used xml in urls before.

Comment: @pat: I added that link to the answer. So far I've spotted the space that needs this.

Comment: thanks, I had tried urlencode before but i wasnt getting the expected answer. Just found out that the USPS API isnt very reliable. Put in some popular zip codes and it returns errors. I hadnt bothered to read the errors assuming they were encoding errors. Now, read through the errors, they are from USPS side and urlencode did actually work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You need to `urlencode` for many more reasons than just a space.  Your string should look like this:  `%3D%3CCityStateLookupRequest%20USERID%3D%22xxxxxxx%22%3E%3CZipCode%20ID%3D%20%220%22%3E%20%0A%3CZip5%3E90210%3C%2FZip5%3E%3C%2FZipCode%3E%3C%2FCityStateLookupRequest%3E`

Comment: Incase anyone is looking for the zip to city conversion, I would suggest http://ziptasticapi.com/. Simple and it works!

Comment: @Brad: thats exactly what I was getting using urlencode. It was my mistake that I did not pay attention to the output. The USPS url worked the first time, I thought it was gonna work for every other zip code too. I kept getting this though: <CityStateLookupResponse>
<ZipCode ID="0">
<Error>
<Number>-2147219040</Number>
<Source>SOLServerTest;SOLServerTest.CallZipCodeDll</Source>
<Description>
This Information has not been included in this Test Server.
</Description>
<HelpFile/>
<HelpContext/>
</Error>
</ZipCode>
</CityStateLookupResponse>

Comment: @pat: Do not use a remote API when you can run it your own and when you know where the data comes from: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/ - geonames.org is a site you need to know.

Comment: @pat Thanks for the shoutout but Ziptasticapi.com is discontinued and I'd suggest people not use it. https://github.com/joshstrange/Ziptastic

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php should get you started if you want to encode the xml into the URL.